# how to define parameterized constructor of abstract class in child class in java

Tags: java

how to define parameterized constructor of abstract class in child class in java

```
abstract class Car {
    protected boolean isSedan;
    protected String seats;

    public Car(boolean isSedan, String seats) {
        this.isSedan = isSedan;
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public boolean getIsSedan() {
        return this.isSedan;
    }

    public String getSeats() {
        return this.seats;
    }

    abstract public String getMileage();
}

public class WagonR extends Car{
    protected int mileage;
    protected boolean isSedan;

    public WagonR(int mileage) {
        super(isSedan,seats); 
        this.mileage=mileage;
    }   
}

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int carType = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
        int carMileage = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        Car wagonR = new WagonR(carMileage);
        wagonR.printCar("WagonR");
    }
}
```

While passing isSedan and seats parameters in super block in WagonR constructor, getting compilation error "Cannot refer to an instance field isSedan while explicitly invoking a constructor" and "Cannot refer to an instance field seats while explicitly invoking a constructor"
**Constraint is while execution only one parameter will be passed like WagonR(carMileage).**

Comment: Why are you declaring `isSedan` in WagonR when it is already declared in the base class?

Comment: after removing isSedan from WagonR problem remains same.

Comment: What do you expect `super(isSedan,seats)` to do? What value are `isSedan` and `seats` supposed to be initialised to?

Comment: i used super to invoke Car(isSedan,seats) constructor from WagonR(mileage), or is there any other way to invoke Car(isSedan, seats) constructor from WagonR(mileage)?

Comment: What value are `isSedan` and `seats` supposed to be initialised to?

Comment: when i pass Car wagonR = new WagonR(carMileage); this should check for whether it is sedan and how many number of seats are there? So just by passing the mileage it should also check for boolean isSedan condition and number of seats

Comment: @khelwood i have got solution by your question. Thanks a lot for that :) I had to just pass the parameter values inside super block rather than passing parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing mistake by passing parameter names in super block rather than passing parameter values using which I wanted to invoke Car constructor.

```
//incorrect
public WagonR(int mileage) {
        super(isSedan,seats);
        this.mileage=mileage;
    }

//correct
public WagonR(int mileage) {
        super(false,"4");
        this.mileage=mileage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WagonR class shoud be like this:

```
public class WagonR extends Car{
    protected int mileage;
    protected boolean isSedan;

    public WagonR(int mileage) {
        super(false, "4"); 
        this.mileage=mileage;
    }

    public WagonR(int mileage, boolean isSedan, String seats) {
        super(isSedan, seats); 
        this.mileage=mileage;
    }

    // And don't forget override method
    @Override
    public String getMileage() {

    }
}
```